# how to call a function inside a class using php

Tags: php

please help me with this example.. I want to call the function inside the class..

**FUNCTION**

```
class myTest(){
       function Me(){
       $x = 2;
       }
}
```

**is this the answer?**

```
$myval = new myTest();
echo $myval;
```

thank you

Comment: Beginner tutorial on objects in PHP http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Comment: `$myval = new myTest(); echo $myval->Me();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first instantiate a new object of type 'myTest' like so:

```
$myObj = new myTest;
```

And then you can use the function like so:

```
$myObj->Me();
```

Note that at present, the function returns nothing so you'll get a 'blank screen'.

If you changed your function to read:

```
return "Hello";
```

Then you would get 'Hello' printed on screen by using the above.

I hope that helps?

Comment: its already accepted.. thanks again H2ONOCK

Answer (score 0):

`$myval = new myTest();` here `$myval` is object of the your Class .

You can call the inside function with just `$myval->Me();`

Comment: Also he needs to add `return $x;`